# Block a is control block(List of Values) block b is database block (detail of each value in Block a)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

Block A - CONTROL BLOCK ( FOR SOME VALIDATION)

```
EMPNO EMPNAME DEPT
12345 XXXX    D1
35245 YYYY    D2
```

BLOCK B - DATABASE BLOCK

```
EMP ADDR - NO.6 XXX STREET
           NEW YORK
CONTACT - 9090909090
EMAIL ID - XXX@XXX.COM
```

Each time of Block A When new form instance trigger - fires execute query in Block B. so that the details will show. 
Problem is when i change something in Block B, without committing if i go to Block A, Block B is getting queried without the changes.

Comment: if you Change without commiting, why you should get tha changes than?

Comment: because this form is a child form of another form.. everything should get commit in the parent form only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is Oracle Forms, and - based on your comment, blocks you displayed belong to a form which is called from its parent form and you don't want to commit here, then you have an option to **`POST`** changes made in this form.

`POST` will write data into the database, but won't perform commit so - if you don't commit and exit the form, nothing will be permanently stored. Therefore, make sure that the parent form really commits, otherwise everything you do in the called form will be lost.

Comment: thats all fine.. my first block A in the child form doing execute query to populate the details in Block B, my changes rollbacks on each time of execute query

Comment: So, did you POST or not?